# Which AWS Service triggered the SNS notifications?

Tags: amazon-sns

I happened to receive suddenly several email notifications from an SNS topic that I had subscribed to sometime back. However, I am unable to find which AWS service is configured to trigger the SNS notifications. Is there a way to trace the AWS Service and events that caused the SNS triggers?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source for AWS Service API calls using **CloudTrail**. According to the AWS docs, **SNS API** calls **can** be logged with **CloudTrail**.

"Amazon SNS is integrated with AWS CloudTrail, a service that provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in Amazon SNS."

**Source**: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Per my understanding, only a limited number of API calls are logged in CloudTrail by Default. For example, SNS event like "Subscribe" gets logged but not the event "Publish". Hence, while I can see who subscribed to the SNS topic, I am unable to trace back to the application that Published message by invoking the topic.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2023, SNS now supports CloudTrail data event logging for the Publish and PublishBatch API actions. More information: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/09/amazon-sns-aws-cloudtrail-data-event-logging-publish-publishbatch-api-actions/

Here's an example of a Publish API request logged in CloudTrail:

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.09",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "EX_PRINCIPAL_ID",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob",
        "accountId": "123456789012",
        "accessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Admin",
                "accountId": "123456789012",
                "userName": "ExampleUser"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2023-08-21T16:44:05Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2023-08-21T16:48:37Z",
    "eventSource": "sns.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "Publish",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "192.0.2.0",
    "userAgent": "aws-cli/1.29.16 md/Botocore#1.31.16 ua/2.0 os/linux#5.4.250-173.369.amzn2int.x86_64 md/arch#x86_64 lang/python#3.8.17 md/pyimpl#CPython cfg/retry-mode#legacy botocore/1.31.16",
    "requestParameters": {
        "topicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:ExampleSNSTopic",
        "message": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "subject": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS",
        "messageStructure": "json",
        "messageAttributes": "HIDDEN_DUE_TO_SECURITY_REASONS"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "messageId": "0787cd1e-d92b-521c-a8b4-90434e8ef840"
    },
    "requestID": "0a8ab208-11bf-5e01-bd2d-ef55861b545d",
    "eventID": "bb3496d4-5252-4660-9c28-3c6aebdb21c0",
    "readOnly": false,
    "resources": [{
        "accountId": "123456789012",
        "type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:ExampleSNSTopic"
    }],
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": false,
    "recipientAccountId": "123456789012",
    "eventCategory": "Data",
    "tlsDetails": {
        "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
        "cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "clientProvidedHostHeader": "sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
}
```